# how to go to an id with article tag from my action php

Tags: php

I have a form with action to go to my request.php after some action i want to go back to my article id that have these form, but it always go to the first id "**info**" in my article tag instead.

here my **index.php**:

```
<div id="main">

<article id="info" class="panel">
  //some text
</article>

<article id="email" class="panel">
  <form action="requestact.php" method="post">

    //some input type

  </form
</article>
</div>
```

here my **requestact.php**:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your ID is not valid')</script>";

header("Refresh:0; url=index.php#email");
```

please help me, thanks.

Comment: You mean, you have multiple articles with the id `info`? Ids have to be unique within a document, so go and fix that first of all. // If you have multiple forms and want each to redirect back to a specific item - then put the item id into a hidden field in the form, so that you can access it server-side.

Comment: it's not error, this echo just for any message box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try storing the url to which you wnat to visit in a specific variable; and then pass it in the header().

For Example:

```
$url = 'index.php?email="this@gmail.com"';
header($url);
```

this will use GET method and will pass the value through url in the index.php page.

**Happy Coding:)**

Comment: Sure. Happy to help.